# select all the rows with the date between 2 datetime columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Columns in the table are

```
ID  Name   SDate            EDate            RNo
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016       12345
```

And the result should be

```
ID  Name   SDate            EDate       MDate              RNo
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016    12/27/2016         12345
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016    12/28/2016         12345
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016    12/29/2016         12345
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016    12/30/2016         12345
1    abc   12/27/2016     12/31/2016    12/31/2016         12345
```

Comment: Do you have one table or two - the title says you're selecting rows in a range; are you getting rows in one table using a date range from another? Or are you selecting a single row and then generating all the `mdate` values? Or multiple rows?

Comment: I have 1 table with 2 datetime columns SDate and EDate. And I want the result set with an extra column as MDate as showed above.

Comment: Is ID the primary key (or at least a unique key) in the table? If not, is there a unique key (perhaps composite) - or might you have duplicate rows? All cases can be addressed, but "how" depends on table structure.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1: Using nested tables

Define a type of date:

```
create type tp as table of date;
/
```

Then use this:

```
select ID, Name, SDate, EDate, x.column_value MDate, RNo
from YOUR_TABLE,
table(cast(multiset(
  select SDate + level - 1
  from dual
  connect by SDate + level - 1 <= EDate
) as tp)) x;
```

---

#### Method 2: Using just connect by

You can use Hierachical query - `CONNECT BY` to do so:

```
select ID, Name, SDate, EDate, 
  sDate + level - 1 MDate,
  RNo
from table
connect by sDate + level - 1 <= EDate;
```

The above works if source table has only one row.

If ID is *unique*, Below should work:

```
select ID, Name, SDate, EDate, 
  sDate + level - 1 MDate,
  RNo
from table
connect by sDate + level - 1 <= EDate
and prior id = id
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

If there is a *compound key* on the table, just `join` on all its columns in the same way as I did with `id` above.

---

#### Method 3: Using connect by and spread of difference

**Using CTE**

```
with spread(lvl) as (
    select level - 1
    from (
        select max(EDate - SDate) + 1 maxdiff
        from my_table
    ) connect by level <= maxdiff
)
select t.id, t.Name, t.SDate, t.EDate,
    SDate + lvl MDate
from my_table t inner join spread s
on EDate - SDate >= lvl;
```

**Without CTE**

```
select t.id, t.Name, t.SDate, t.EDate,
    SDate + lvl MDate
from my_table t
inner join (
    select level - 1 lvl
    from (
        select max(EDate - SDate) + 1 maxdiff
        from my_table
    ) connect by level <= maxdiff
) s
on EDate - SDate >= lvl;
```

Comment: how to get level value instead of 5?

Comment: level <= 5. Instead of providing a value 5 here, how can I get the value dynamically?

Comment: On the date difference of EDate and SDate

Comment: This will work only if the input table has exactly one row. To see that, create a sample table with two rows and run the query - notice what happens.

Comment: The mechanism may be the same, but with some extra conditions in CONNECT BY - depending on his/her answer to the questions I asked in my Comment to him/her (under the original post).

Comment: It should work. A somewhat more efficient alternative is to not use a join, but instead to add conditions with the PRIOR operator to CONNECT BY.

Comment: When I create a view using the above script and select query the view, it gives me an error ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Comment: checked that as well. then it gave me single row

Comment: select ID, Name, SDate, EDate, 
  sDate + level - 1 MDate,
  RNo
from table
connect by sDate + level - 1 <= EDate
and prior id = id
and prior sys_guid() is not null;